# The definite article in the first position

Tags: adjective-degrees

Can I use "the" before "best reflects" in my sentence? I can use it after "personality" but I am not sure it sounds natural before "the best reflects..."
"The room which (best) reflects my personality (best) is my study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of these are natural:

> 1. The room that best reflects my personality is my study.
> 2. The room that reflects my personality best is my study.
> 3. The room that reflects my personality the best is my study.

The word "best" makes "the" appropriate in both sentences. Its position does not affect that.

Note that #1 might sound old-fashioned or formal to some listeners, especially young people. #3 might sound the most native.

I have used "that" instead of "which" because doing so with restrictive clauses is recommended by many style guides, not because it is better. It was a Brit who popularized the guideline, but the British seem to follow it less than Americans.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. Do you mean I can use "the" in both? 

1. The room that *the* best reflects my personality is my study.
2. The room that reflects my personality *the* best is my study.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. #1 in your comment does not work. #2 works well. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you! But why exactly is it wrong in "The room that the best reflects my personality is my study." I feel that it's wrong, but I can't explain why. As I am not a native speaker I really have to know the rules :S

Comment: LOL. If I'd understood your very interesting question the first time around, I might not have answered, because I don't have a good explanation. I think the better question is why #2 **does** work. Feel free to un-accept my answer when a better one comes along.

Comment: No, I definitely wouldn't unaccept your answer :). I am trying to find a rule. Perhaps it doesn't exist. Perhaps some things are not based on rules...